# AWS Device Farm CLI Testsuite Filteration

Tags: appium, aws-cli, aws-device-farm

I am using AWS Device Farm to run Appium test cases through the AWS CLI (for android apps).
I want to run test suites selectively on Device Farm. I went through AWS CLI's documentation (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/devicefarm/schedule-run.html) to determine what the possible parameters are to the schedule-run command. I am not able to determine how I can specify the name of the test suites that I want to run. How can I pass the names of the test suites that I want to run through the schedule run command ?

Comment: If you found the answer useful please mark is as accepted answer so that others can benefit from it.

Answer (score 0):

I work for the AWS Device Farm team.

1. If you are looking to run specific tests then using testng.xml would be the way to go about this. 
   The xml file should be placed under src/test/resources during packaging. 
   Today Device Farm supports basic filtering and not advanced features like groups. priority etc.
2. If you are just look for parameters to pass to a schedule run command here is a 2 part guide to achieve that: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/get-started-with-the-aws-device-farm-cli-and-calabash-part-1-creating-a-device-farm-run-for-android-calabash-test-scripts/

Hope this helps.